# How to get Java RMI process not to terminate

Tags: java, rmi

Node.java:

```
import java.rmi.Naming;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.io.Serializable; 

public class Node implements NodeInterface,Serializable {
    
    public Node(String URL) throws RemoteException {
        try {
            if (!(URL.equals("0"))) {
                NodeInterface nodeinterface;
                nodeinterface = (NodeInterface) Naming.lookup("0");
                nodeinterface.join("0");
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(String.format("Encountering issues while constructing the server class. Error %s%n", e.getMessage()));
        }
    }
      
    public boolean join (String nodeURL) throws RemoteException {
        synchronized (this) {
            try {
                System.out.println("printing from inside node 0");
                return true;
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                throw new RemoteException(String.format("Error %s", e.getMessage()));
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Node node = new Node(args[0]);
            Naming.rebind(args[0],node);
            //System.out.println
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

NodeInterface.java:

```
import java.rmi.Remote;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;

public interface NodeInterface extends Remote {
  public boolean join (String nodeURL) throws RemoteException;

}
```

When I compile this code and execute `java Node 0` the process terminates and executing `java Node 1` produces the output `printing from inside node 0`.

I'd like to see this work as follows:
In terminal 1:

```
Java Node 0
```

Then, in terminal 2:

```
Java Node 1
```

Then I would expect to see in terminal 1:

```
printing from inside node 0
```

What changes to my code would I have to make to make this possible?

Comment: `Node` should extend `UnicastRemoteObject`. It isn't a remote object at all at the moment, it is being serialized holus-bolus to the Registry.

Comment: Your title has nothing to do with your question. NB It does not need to implement `Serializable` if it is meant to be a remote object.